# Add 'Gregwar's Image class' to Laravel

Tags: php, git, class, laravel

I want add this class to laravel - https://github.com/Gregwar/Image

There is 'Using with composer' - I added this line to composer.json

```
"gregwar/image": "dev-master"
```

I was run:

```
php artisan optimize
composer dump-autoload
```

But if i want use this class - have this error:

```
Class 'Image' not found
```

class is installed (by composer) in root: vendor/gregwar/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the readme says, you have to "require" it using its namespace:

```
use Gregwar\Image\Image;
```

So your code should look like:

```
<?php

use Gregwar\Image\Image;

echo Image::open('test.png')
    ->sepia()
    ->jpeg();
```

Comment: If I place namespace - get error syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)'

Comment: 'use' needs to go at the top of you script before you define any classes

Comment: Please share your source code. You are adding it in the wrong place.